# Removing colors from an image in python

Tags: python, colors

This code removes red but I can’t get it to work for removing other colors.

```py
def removeRed(inLines, outfile):
    for i in range(3, len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        nums = line.split()
        outLine = ''
        for j in range(len(nums)):
            if j % 3 == 0:
                outLine = outLine + '0 '
            else:
                outLine = outLine + nums[j] + ' '
        outfile.write(outLine + '\n')
```